# flag not loading with intlTelInput library

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to "echo" a number phone in the first input value of my form.

The problem is that when doing so, the flag (which should be the flag of your country) does not appear on the 1st input.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/css/intlTelInput.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

</head>


<?php
  error_reporting(0);

  $phone1="0845124578";

?>

<body>

      <form action="deuxiemeBis.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name ="phone1" id="phone1" value="<?php echo $phone1;?>">


            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name ="phone5" id="phone5" value="<?php echo $phone5;?>">

            <button type="submit">valider</button>
      </form>

</body>

</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

<script>


$("#phone1").intlTelInput({
      initialCountry: "auto",
      geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
          var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
          callback(countryCode);
        });
      },
      utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});



$("#phone5").intlTelInput({
      initialCountry: "auto",
      geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
          var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
          callback(countryCode);
        });
      },
     utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"

});



var telInput1 = $("#phone1"),
telInput5 = $("#phone5"),
errorMsg = $("#error-msg"),
validMsg = $("#valid-msg");

telInput1.intlTelInput({
      utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});


telInput5.intlTelInput({
      utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});


</script>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I can't figure out how this problem occurs, any help ?

**p.s:**

1) You should be abble to run this code without making any change (I wanted to give a JSFiddle example but it did not work).

2) for the example I did not add the call to the database, but I directly affected `$phone1` with a value.

Comment: That is because the number you enter does not match with the country you have edited.  Try adding valid number and reload and check.

Answer (score 0):

The flags are located in build/img/flags.png and build/img/flags@2x.png
Make sure you have pointed to them!

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you need to make sure the `intlTelInput` and `utilsScript` are loaded before you set the value?